# Multiple Wordpress Sites Attacked at Once

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

So, i'm having a problem with multiple **Wordpress** websites being attacked at once, i ran '`last`' on my server and didn't find anything strange, all of the IP's are exactly the same and the number of logged in users matches what was expected.

Google warns me that all websites contain pages that direct users to 
 *freemit.wz.cz* and *handicraftmag.com*

We have run malware checks and they clear on both sites. Wordpress was not up to date but it is now. Any idea what more we can do to ensure everything is working properly?

As far as Plugins are concerned i'm running the following.

```
Compress JPEG & PNG images - Version 2.0.2  Active
Contact Form 7 - Version 4.4.2  Active
MyThemeShop Theme/Plugin Updater - Version 1.3  Active
W3 Total Cache - Version 0.9.5.1    Inactive
Wordfence Security - Version 6.2.5  Active
WP Shortcode by MyThemeShop - Version 1.4.2 Active
WP Tab Widget - Version 1.2.5   Active
Yoast SEO: News - Version 3.3   Active
Yoast SEO Premium - Version 3.4
```

Comment: Did you use any WordPress security plugin?

Comment: @OwaisAlam yes, Wordfence but not the Premium Edition